# Website creation from scratch

Tags: html

I want to learn to make websites. Know the basics of HTML and CSS, now learning JS. Tell me if I want to write their own websites not using CMS what I need to use an additional?

Comment: You clearly didn't read the stuff you were told to read before asking your "question". As a result you asked a question is that low quality and not allowed on this site. I suggest you visit the [help] and read it before asking another question as you will be question banned quickly if all of your participation is this low quality.

Answer (score 0):

You must need to have basic knowledge of html, css and js and you can use nodejs which acts as server and client to create websites.